# Continuously streaming data with Boost::ASIO without closing socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp

I'm trying to build an application that:

a) Runs an FDM (flight dynamics model) internally, and manages the flight data

b) Accepts connections on a TCP socket

c) Serves the flight data over said socket.

I've currently managed to get a simple string sent over TCP on my a local socket using the examples/tutorials on the Boos::ASIO website here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0_b1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html

My trouble is simply that the connection closes after a single string is written, and I don't know how to keep the connection open and continuously send the data until the simulation is finished (or a stop signal is sent from the listening application).

I also have the FDM working (currently using JSBSim, and borrowing heavily from their included sample code), and can print flight data to stdout no problem. The Boost:ASIO documentation shows a few examples on how to build a server that constantly listens for messages received from the client, but none that send a stream of data out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To send a stream of data out, you can use the free functions with `boost::asio::streambuf`.

Here's a simple demo that sends its own source to each client:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/posix/stream_descriptor.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace io = boost::asio;
namespace ip = io::ip;
using boost::system::error_code;
using boost::make_shared;
using ip::tcp;

void start_accept(io::io_service& svc, tcp::acceptor& acc) {
    // per-connection lifetimes:
    auto sock = make_shared<tcp::socket>(svc);

    acc.async_accept(*sock, [sock,&svc,&acc](error_code ec) {
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::cout << "connection from " << sock->remote_endpoint() << "\n";

            // copy source file to buffer data
            auto data = make_shared<io::streambuf>();
            std::ostream(data.get()) << std::ifstream("main.cpp").rdbuf();

            // now write the whole story
            io::async_write(*sock, *data, [sock,data/*keep alive*/](error_code ec, size_t transferred){});

            // accept new connections too
            start_accept(svc, acc);
        }
    });
}

int main()
{
    io::io_service svc;
    tcp::acceptor acc(svc, tcp::endpoint(ip::address(), 6767));

    start_accept(svc, acc);

    svc.run();
}
```

Note that for simplicity I put the full buffer in memory first, assuming you can do that (you said *"and can print flight data to stdout no problem"*). So, you could just write different things to the stream (the `ostream` line in my example).

Comment: This is immensely helpful, thank you! I also found that as long as I wasn't recreating the acceptor and socket every time in the loop (which is what the boost examples show), I could keep the connection alive. Another question is this: for async writes like this, will the connection stay alive throughout the program, even if you don't constantly write to it/keep the buffer full?

Comment: The lifetime of the socket determines the lifetime of the connection (unless the remote end closes it, or `close()`/`shutdown()` are called explicitly)